# Colored output to screen in C

Tags: c

I've wrote this very basic code-lines with colored output:

```
printf("\033[1;32m"); // boldgreen code: \033[1;32m according to: 
                         http://web.theurbanpenguin.com/adding-color-to-your-output-from-c/
puts("Enter username:");
gets(user);
```

In my computer evreything works fine and I get colored output as expected:
[image]

but in other computers I get this Output:

```
\033[1;32mEnter username:
```

I have to say that all my #includes are fine, Im just doing copy-paste to another computer & if thats important Im using Visual Studio in both Computers.

seems like basic thing but I don't understand why thats happend.
Thanks for helpers.

Comment: You just discovered that not all terminals support ANSI escape codes. Nothing you can do about that.

Comment: @usr2564301 if thats the problem as you say, I should avoid from using ANSI codes right?

Comment: Nah, not necessarily. You could add "must support ANSI" to your program system requirements. Or you could make it an option, where a command line argument flag toggles colors on or off (you'll have to pick a default, though).

Comment: @usr2564301 Got it, thanks alot.

Comment: You can try to detect whether the terminal is ANSI, and also have a command line flag. GNU `ls` does this with `--color=always`

Comment: @torstenvl How can I do it in Visual Studio?

Comment: BE is just an advanced text editor. You need to do it in the code you type using this editor

Comment: You seem to be using *gets*. Don't, ever. It's fundamentally broken (no way to prevent user from creating buffer overflow by too long input), and has been removed from C. Write your own line reading function (using *fgets* + trimming, or maybe *getchar* in a loop).

Comment: @hyde Got it! Thanks, I'll fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most terminals support colors. The problem is sending the right escape code. For the Windows command line, you have do a different escape sequence. [There is a wikipedia entry that describes how to do an escape in different environments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Windows).